# Get column value corresponding to the idxmax from another column per group

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe consisting of 3 columns and n rows.

My dataframe before grouping looks like

```
Index    Max_Mass (kg/m)    Max_Diameter (m)
1             10                   1
2             20                   2
3             30                   3

200           5                    4
201           60                   3
202           20                   2

300           90                   1
301           3                    1
302           10                   1

400           100                  1
401           10                   1
402           10                   1
```

I group the dataframe by cutting it every 100 rows so that I can find the maximum value of a specific column every 100th row using:

```
groups = output_df.groupby(pd.cut(output_df.index, range(0,len(output_df), 100)))
```

I am using the below to find the maximums of column 'Max Mass (kg/m)':

```
groups.max()['Max Mass (kg/m)']
```

I now want to make another df which will contain the max value found and the index of that value. How do I retrieve the index? I have tried using the below, but from my understanding, it only works for a single value, while the line above returns me a column of all maximums.

```
(groups.max()['Max Mass (kg/m)']).getidx()
```

My expected output (for the DataFrame above) would be

My new dataframe that I want to create should look like;

```
Index    Max_Mass (kg/m)    Max_Diameter (m)
3             30                   3
201           60                   3
300           90                   1
400           100                  1
```

Comment: Not clear what your data or expected output should look like. Can you provide a [mcve] please?

Comment: @coldspeed updated

Comment: It looks like in the sample data you are cutting every 3 rows.

Comment: @coldspeed In the sample data, there are 402+ rows, in my original edit, I had the '...' in place after every three rows to symbolise a continuation until the next set of 200 rows.

Comment: Yes, I get it. Although, if you are grouping every 400 rows, then you should only have two groups here: first for rows b/w 0-399, and second for rows b/w 400 and 402 (as far as I can tell by your post). Can you check again please?

Comment: @coldspeed Yes you are correct. I made an edit to fix this mistake. Take it that my goal is now to get the maximum by cutting every 200 rows.

Comment: I appreciate you taking the time to address my comments, but it seems like the example is cutting every 100 rows :)

Comment: @coldspeed Correct, fixed. Take it that my goal is now to get the maximum by cutting every 100 rows haha

Comment: This code should work for you: https://pastebin.com/raw/csFwzzKU

Comment: @coldspeed Legend mate, works well! How can I upvote your solution?

Comment: I've promoted my comment to an answer, so you can accept/upvote it now. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Comments inlined.

```
# Initialise the grouper.
grouper = df.Index // 100
# Get list of indices corresponding to the max using `apply`.
idx = df.groupby(grouper).apply(
          lambda x: x.set_index('Index')['Max_Mass (kg/m)'].idxmax())
# Compute the max and update the other columns based on `idx` computed previously.
v = df.groupby(grouper, as_index=False)['Max_Mass (kg/m)'].max()
v['Index'] = idx.values
v['Max_Diameter (m)'] = df.loc[df.Index.isin(v.Index), 'Max_Diameter (m)'].values
```

```
print(v)
   Max_Mass (kg/m)  Index  Max_Diameter (m)
0               30      3                 3
1               60    201                 3
2               90    300                 1
3              100    400                 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using groups.max() you can use `groups.idxmax()`. Then use the index to get the max values. Now you have everything you need.

Comment: I would suggest answering the question in such a way that there's more code than sentences... best way to get rep on this tag.